# Can I see the final state of a branch in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I use Gerrit at work for code reviews, and I am very pleased with the workflow it encourages and the code review features it has.

However, it seems to lack one feature that I've grown used to with Github / GitLab / BitBucket: the ability to see the whole final state of a feature branch (including the changes from all commits on that branch).

For long branches, where development required backtracking to undo previous attempts, this has lead to requests to squash the branch into a single commit so its final state can be reviewed to make sure the final state makes sense. However, I strongly dislike losing the intermediate commits only to facilitate code review, so I'd like to avoid this.

**Does Gerrit have any way I can look at the final state of a branch?** Or more generally, at the diff between two arbitrary commits? (In that case, it would be the head of the branch and the commit it branched off of).

If this can be achieved with some sort of plugin, that would also be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a bad idea to squash the branch into a single commit because you'll lose the feature branch commit history.

Gerrit doesn't have a diff feature as you want and AFAIK there's no plugins to perform that but, I think, the change page has everything you need to analyze a merge commit.

Suppose you have the following situation:

```
A --- B    <== master
 \
  \
   C --- D <== feature
```

And you want to merge the feature to master to get this:

```
A --- B --- E <== master
 \         /
  \       /
   C --- D    <== feature
```

In the change page for the merge commit you can select how Gerrit will make the diff (Parent 1, Parent 2 or Auto Merge), like showed in the example following.

Parent 1:

[image]

Parent 2:

[image]

Auto Merge:

[image]

You can also see all the commits that will be merged by the feature branch:

[image]

Note: I'm using Gerrit 3.0.3